# elasticsearch cluster node not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elk

Here I am using two server one master and one node.
I have set up elasticsearch cluster which is up and running fine, but when I am checking number of nodes on master server , only one node is showing, but it should show two nodes.

Here is my configuration:

**master (node -1) server elasticsearch.yml conf#**

```
cluster.name: my-application
node.name: node-1
#node.attr.rack: r1
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 10.542.60.54
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["10.542.60.54", "10.542.67.92"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["10.238.41.22"]
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
node.master: true
node.data: true
transport.port: 9300
node.ingest: true
```

**node - 2 : elasticsearch.yml configuration:**

```
cluster.name: my-application
node.name: node-2
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 10.542.67.92
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["10.542.60.54","10.542.67.92"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["10.542.60.54"]
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
node.master: false
node.data: true
node.ingest: true
transport.port: 9300
```

**When I am checking details of my cluster, only one node is coming:**

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "my-application",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}
```

Comment: can you share your cluster startup logs when it tries to form a cluster, it shows the reason why it's not able to connect to other nodes

Comment: Thanks @ArnavSinghChauhan for your response, do you want var/log/elasticsearch/clustername.log content?

Comment: FYI: @ArnavSinghChauhan
[2022-02-03T01:01:31,294][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [node-1] node name [node-1], node ID [Ez2NYRfYQRiLd5HVCP_dzg], cluster name [my-application]

Comment: yes, cluster.log output i need, 
can you add the startup logs in the questions itself?

Comment: There is an error in the network.host, with this IP, I can found the other IP. add a sub ip